# Different results using Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I have this very simple Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[Column[{-9^t, u^t}], {t, .9, 1.1}, {u, -10, 10, 1}]
```

And thought this should give the same result – but it doesn't:

[image]

I am confused and don't know what the problem is.

Same here:

```
Table[i^1.1, {i, -10, -8}]
```

and

```
-10^1.1
-9^1.1
-8^1.1
```

These are the respective results:

[image]

I hope, I'm not missing something very obvious.

Comment: `(-9)^t`, and I am assuming you start `u` from `-9` not `-10`.

Comment: Maybe it's just my mathematics, as I think I'm confused by that if I make 9^2 I get 81, and for (-9)^2, I also get 81. However, calculating 9^1.1 provides 11.2116, but (-9)^1.1 provides -10.6628 - 3.46457i. But I see that I need the brackets.

Comment: Compare `ComplexExpand[(-10)^y, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]` and `ComplexExpand[(-x)^2, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]` for instance.

Comment: Yes, it is your mathematics. Clear counter example: `(-8)^1/3` is `-2` not `2`. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation.

Comment: Yes, I can see where I went wrong. Thanks for helping clarifingying it.